# Usando DB in Middleware Lumen

Tags: lumen

Estou tentando obter uma instancia da classe DB dentro do meu Middleware e esta dando o seguinte erro:

Class 'DB' not found

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    $results = DB::select("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
    var_dump($results);
    return $next($request);

}
```

Como faço para utilizar a classe DB nesse ponto do codigo?

Comment: já tentou botar uma barra na frente? Comigo funciona por que o autoloader não busca no raíz: ``\DB::select(...)``

Comment: segue o mesmo erro

Comment: Olha, certamente é o caminho pra classe que tá faltando. Nunca usei o Lumen, mas não deve ser longe disso. Dá uma olhada na documentação: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/database

Answer (score 0):

Adicione apos o namespace da class Middleware a seguinte linha:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`